# redirecting snowflake to a different s3 endpoint

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We develop an S3 proxy product. It implements part of the S3 rest api.
Is it possible to configure snowflake to a different ip address (like "--endpoint-url" in aws cli).
Thanks, Tzahi

Answer (score 0):

You can point snowflake to S3 buckets for reading/written importing/exporting data, and you can make eternal tables to S3 buckets, which means, yes you can redirect them, but as for their internal S3 no.

Of those two, redirecting a bucket you already control seems of low value, as you control it.. and the later you cannot do.

Comment: ref: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config.html